# DataNucleus on AppEngine not returning any results

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-sql, datanucleus

I just about tried everything, but I am not receiving any results when running a simple SQL query running on the following target platform: Google AppEngine + Google Cloud SQL datastore using DataNucleus (all on Google Cloud Platform).
I have deployed a basic Java Servlet and set up a simple MySql table. Here are the details. What is most frustrating is that I don't know how to get more information to progress. So your help is much appreciated. So again, there is no error, just no results in the result set.

#### The Database

Of course, I am 100% sure there is data in the table. My database (MySql) has the following table in the schema 'vicparkhoney':

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` ( `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL);
```

The following query, directly entered in MySql workbench gives two results:

```
SELECT * FROM vicparkhoney.mytable;
```

results:

```
name
===========
Name1
Name2
```

(even after several reconnects for those wondering if I had committed the inserts...)

And this will be no surprise to you, the following query returns one result:

```
SELECT * FROM vicparkhoney.mytable n WHERE n.name = 'Name1';

name
===========
Name1
```

#### The Java Code

I don't get this same result when running the JPA query through DataNucleus. This is my Servlet code:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
Query q = em.createQuery("select n from MyTable n where n.name = 'Name1'");
List results = q.getResultList();
Iterator iter = results.iterator();
MyTable n = null;
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    n = (MyTable)iter.next();
}
em.close();
```

This is the `MyTable` code for the Entity class:

```
package com.vicparkhoney.backend.bean;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table( name = "mytable" )
public class MyTable {

    @Basic
    @Id
    private String name;

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

#### The JPA config

This is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"         
    version="1.0">

<persistence-unit name="transactions-optional">
    <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <class>com.vicparkhoney.backend.bean.MyTable</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="datanucleus.mapping.Schema" value="vicparkhoney"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

#### The Log

I am wondering if there is a way to get more info in the logs as to what the exact SQL is that DataNucleus is running. I used:

```
DataNucleus.level=FINEST
DataNucleus.Datastore.Native=FINEST
```

The logs:

```
20:08:55.937
org.datanucleus.query.JPQLSingleStringParser <init>: JPQL Single-String with "select n from MyTable n where n.name = 'Name1'"
20:08:56.141
org.datanucleus.store.query.AbstractJPQLQuery compileInternal: JPQL Query : Compiling "SELECT n FROM MyTable n WHERE n.name = 'Name1'"
20:08:56.339
org.datanucleus.store.query.AbstractJPQLQuery compileInternal: JPQL Query : Compile Time = 198 ms
20:08:56.340
org.datanucleus.store.query.AbstractJPQLQuery compileInternal: QueryCompilation:
  [from:ClassExpression(alias=n)]
  [filter:DyadicExpression{PrimaryExpression{n.name}  =  Literal{Name1}}]
  [symbols: n type=com.vicparkhoney.backend.bean.MyTable]
20:08:56.342
com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.JPQLQuery performExecute: JPQL Query : Executing "SELECT n FROM MyTable n WHERE n.name = 'Name1'" ...
20:08:56.342
com.google.appengine.datanucleus.MetaDataValidator validate: Performing appengine-specific metadata validation for com.vicparkhoney.backend.bean.MyTable
20:08:56.344
com.google.appengine.datanucleus.MetaDataValidator validate: Finished performing appengine-specific metadata validation for com.vicparkhoney.backend.bean.MyTable
20:08:56.628
org.datanucleus.store.StoreDataManager registerStoreData: Managing Persistence of Class : com.vicparkhoney.backend.bean.MyTable [Table : com.vicparkhoney.backend.bean.MyTable, InheritanceStrategy : new-table]
20:08:57.342
com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.JPQLQuery performExecute: Query compiled as : Kind=com.vicparkhoney.backend.bean.MyTable Filter : __key__=mytable("Name1") [QUERY-TYPE=NORMAL]
20:08:57.439
com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery performExecute: Executing query in datastore for SELECT n FROM MyTable n WHERE n.name = 'Name1'
20:08:58.930
com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection <init>: Created ManagedConnection using DatastoreService = com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl@9355b6
20:08:58.937
org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl allocateConnection: Connection added to the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@56c36c for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@15f65a1 in factory=ConnectionFactory:nontx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@3817d7]
20:08:58.938
com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.JPQLQuery performExecute: JPQL Query : Execution Time = 2596 ms
20:08:59.150
org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl closeAllConnections: Connection found in the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@56c36c for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@15f65a1 in factory=ConnectionFactory:nontx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@3817d7] but owner object closing so closing connection
20:08:59.220
org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl$1 managedConnectionPostClose: Connection removed from the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@56c36c for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@15f65a1 in factory=ConnectionFactory:nontx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@3817d7]
20:08:59.220
org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl disconnectObjectProvidersFromCache: Level 1 Cache cleared
20:08:59.223
org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl close: Object Manager "org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@15f65a1" closed
```

Comment: Neil, in regards to URL=appengine, I simply following this link:https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview I will update the original post with the appengine-web.xml to show the MySql URL.

Comment: I did the little sql exercise and that worked without DataNucleus. I changed the persistence.xml so it contains: `<property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:google:mysql://[projid:db-instance]/[dbname]?user=root"/>`. I now get the following error (I saw you commented on others having same problem) `There is no available StoreManager of type "jdbc". Make sure ... put the relevant DataNucleus store plugin in your CLASSPATH and if defining a connection via JNDI or DataSource you also need to provide ... property "datanucleus.storeManagerType"` - any ideas?

Comment: please accept the answer, or post WHY you think it doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 1):

*"Google AppEngine"* originally came with just its own "NoSQL" database known as `GAE/Datastore`. Google provided their own `DataNucleus` plugin to allow persistence to this, called **datanucleus-appengine.jar**. This datastore required `datanucleus.ConnectionURL` to be set to *appengine*. If using this then you would be using very old jars since the Google plugin jar would not work with anything recent.

They then added on *"Google CloudSQL"*, which comes with a `MySQL/MariaDB` database. The DataNucleus project provides its own plugin to persist to this, called **datanucleus-rdbms.jar**. Using this you can use recent DataNucleus project jars. This datastore requires `datanucleus.ConnectionURL` to be set to something starting with *jdbc*.

You are currently using the GAE/Datastore database and not MySQL (so your tests of running things manually in MySQL are all well and good but you haven't configured your persistence layer to use that!). You need to fix the ConnectionURL and make sure you have the datanucleus-rdbms jar in your CLASSPATH. Further to that, read documentation from the relevant sites ([Google AppEngine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview) if wanting to use the GAE/Datastore database, or [DataNucleus itself](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/index.html) if wanting to persist to mySQL).